# Intersection of Sobolev Spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Suppose $\Omega$ is a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with a "nice" boundary. We have the Sobolev spaces $W^{k,2}(\Omega)$, which are all contained within each other: $W^{m,2}(\Omega)\subset W^{k,2}(\Omega)$ if $m>k$. What is the intersection
$$\bigcap_{k}W^{k,2}(\Omega)\,?$$
Could it be $C^\infty(\bar{\Omega})$, the infinitely differentiable functions on the closure of $\Omega$?

(In the case I'm interested in, the boundary of $\Omega$ is just a bunch of hyperplanes and their intersections.  In fact, $\Omega$ is just an $n$-simplex.)

And could I deduce from this that $C^\infty(\bar{\Omega})$ is a nuclear Fréchet space?

Comment: You may look up on Sobolev embedding theorems into Holder continuous functions. At present, you have the added advantage of Fourier transform on Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Yes, if the *niceness* of the boundary allows an extension operator for the Sobolev spaces on $\Omega$. This is explained, e.g., at the end of chapter 14 of the book *Introduction to Functional Analysis* of Meise and Vogt.

Comment: The $\epsilon/\delta$-condition of Peter Jones and the work of Luke Rogers about extension operators should be relevant.